# Run a function inside an anonymous function inside event listener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, anonymous-function

Just working on debounce feature and found this piece of code that seems to be doing the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
  };

  function searchUsers () {
    // some code irrelevant to this question (...)
  };

  var myEfficientFn = debounce(searchUsers, 450);

  document.getElementById("search").addEventListener('input', myEfficientFn);

});
```

Above seem to work well.

But I was curious if I can pass `debounce` function straight to `addEventListener` instead of saving it first in a variable `myEfficentFn`.

So I removed line `var myEfficientFn = debounce(searchUsers, 450);` from code and changed the last line to:

```
   getElementById("search").addEventListener('input', function() {
     debounce(searchUsers, 450);
   });
```

but it stopped working. Why?

Comment: Why did you wrap the `debounce()` call in an anonymous function? Remove it and it will work: `.addEventListener('input', debounce(...))`

Comment: `debounce` returns a function, not a value. To call the function you'd have to use `debounce(searchUsers, 450)();` or you can just use it in addEventListener.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`debounce` is a function that, when called, returns *another function*, one which in your original code, is called when the event triggers:

```
  var myEfficientFn = debounce(searchUsers, 450);
  document.getElementById("search").addEventListener('input', myEfficientFn);
```

In contrast, in your second code, you're calling `debounce` *inside* the event listener. `debounce` returns a function, but you're never calling it: with

```
debounce(searchUsers, 450);
```

you have an unused function expression, kind of like having

```
const someVar = () => console.log('hi');
```

without ever using `someVar` later.

Pass the `debounce` call (which returns the function you want as the event listener) directly into `addEventListener` instead:

```
document.getElementById("search").addEventListener('input', debounce(searchUsers, 450));
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers left out a little bit of info that would help you understand what's happening:

```
getElementById("search").addEventListener('input', function() { // <--- this function gets called on click
  debounce(searchUsers, 450); // this is a function, not a function call
});


getElementById("search").addEventListener('input', function(ev) { // <--- this function gets called on click
  debounce(searchUsers, 450)(ev); // this is how you call the function returned by debounce
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A short explanation;

The `debounce` function returns a function which is run by the event listener.

```
return function()
...
```

Your first approach saves the returned function to a variable and the even listener runs it.

```
addEventListener('input', myEfficientFn);
...
```

Your second approach gets the returned function within another function and no one really runs it.

```
debounce(searchUsers, 450);    //WHo runs the returned function?
...
```

Solution in your own context - run the returned function!

```
getElementById("search").addEventListener('input', function(e) {
     debounce(searchUsers, 450)(e);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't have to wrap it inside an anonymous function, you can simply use:

```
.addEventListener('input', debounce(searchUsers, 450))
```